# Next Js Vercel 405 Method Not Allowed in Stripe Payment Integration on Live Version

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, vercel

[Vercel Stripe 405 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szs4F.png)

Hey, I'm facing an issue with Stripe Payment Integration. When I test it locally, everything works fine. However, after pushing the code to Vercel, I get a "405 Method Not Allowed" error. Can anyone help me figure out and fix this problem?

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
});

export default async function POST(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const orderData = req.body;

      if (!orderData || !Array.isArray(orderData.items)) {
        console.error("Invalid order data:", orderData);
        throw new Error(
          "Invalid order data or lineItems missing or not an array"
        );
      }

      const lineItems = orderData.items.map((product) => ({
        quantity: product.quantity,
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          unit_amount: product.price * 100,
          product_data: {
            name: product.name,
          },
        },
      }));

      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: lineItems,
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/thank-you`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/`,
      });

      res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
      res.redirect(302, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error creating Stripe session:", err);
      res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}

My Stripe API Code
```

please anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: There must be a difference between your local env and your Vercel deployed code. You should double check your integration and see what is the difference. According to the screenshot you are referring to, it seems that your own endpoint is replying with 405 and not Stripe API.